# Por que mi prototype da undefined?

Tags: javascript, poo

Sé que puede parecer un error tonto, pero no se por que mi prototype da undefined

```
class Persona {
  constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
    this.nombre = nombre
    this.edad = edad
    this.hobbies = hobbies
    this.amigos = amigos

  }

  getHobbies() {
    Persona.prototype.addFriend = function() {
         return (this.hobbies)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te da **undefined** sencillamente porque **solo estas asignando una funcion al prototipo de la clase, mas NO la estas ejecutando**.

Asumo que tu nisiquiera estas ejecutando el metodo `getHobbies`, por lo tanto nunca se esta seteando tu prototype.

Asi que simplemente debes llamarlo:

```js
class Persona {
  constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
    this.nombre = nombre
    this.edad = edad
    this.hobbies = hobbies
    this.amigos = amigos

  }

  getHobbies() {
    Persona.prototype.addFriend = function() {
         return (this.hobbies)
    }
    return this.addFriend();
  }
}

const persona = new Persona("juan", 16, ["tomar cerveza", "jugar"], ["julian", "andres"]);
console.log(persona.getHobbies());
```

Por cierto, ojo con las llaves, te hacia falta una llave de cierre `}` en tu codigo original, de todas maneras eso que estas haciendo de por si no es adecuado, permiteme corregirlo por ti:

```js
class Persona {
  constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
    this.nombre = nombre
    this.edad = edad
    this.hobbies = hobbies
    this.amigos = amigos

  }

  get getHobbies() {
    return this.addFriend();
  }
}

//Los prototipos deberian ser declarados siempre fuera de la clase y ademas justo
//despues de crear la clase y antes de hacer cualquier instancia a esta.
Persona.prototype.addFriend = function(){ return this.hobbies };

const persona = new Persona("juan", 16, ["tomar cerveza", "jugar"], ["julian", "andres"]);
console.log(persona.getHobbies);
```

Como vemos, ahora funciona correctamente y esta mejor organizado el codigo, no solo eso, si no que como buena practica, te aconsejo **NUNCA** asignar prototipos dentro de metodos de la clase, puesto que:

La idea de modificar el prototipo de una clase es que todas las instancias de este tengan nuevos metodos o propiedades y los compartan.

Entonces el hecho de asignar prototipos dentro de los metodos de una clase se hace ahora un poco turbio deacuerdo a esta definicion...