# Por que no mi prototype no retorna lo que pido?

Tags: javascript, poo

No sé cual es el error, se que debe ser algo muy sencillo, pero estoy empezando a entrar en el mundo de la programacion, quiero devolver el nombre de la propiedad amigos, separado de la edad que puedan tener

```
class Persona {
    constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
      this.nombre = nombre
      this.edad = edad
      this.hobbies = hobbies
      this. amigos = amigos

    }
getFriends() {   
      Persona.prototype.returnFriend = function() {
        return this.amigos.nombre
        
   }
   return this.returnFriend();
```

Comment: Que tal DingoMandingo, al parecer no le estas añadiendo amigos y por ende no le estas añadiendo ninguna persona a la clase por eso no te retorna nada o lo malentendi?

Comment: @DingoMandingo tu codigo siquera compila. Seguro que lo estas mostrando todo? Agrega al menos la parte relevante de tu codigo

Comment: `amigos` no contiene ninguna propiedad `nombre`. Si quieres acceder a las dos, es por aparte: `this.nombre`, `this.amigos`. Saludos

Comment: Esto es demasiadamente similar a una pregunta que ya habia respondido, sera la misma persona?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Por que mi prototype da undefined?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/366965/por-que-mi-prototype-da-undefined)

Comment: Porfavor deberias tener en cuenta mis sugerencias, no es buena idea que tengas un prototype dentro de un metodo de la clase, ademas si lo tienes dentro de la clase lo unico que estas haciendo es que cada vez que llamas a `getFriends` estas volviendo a reasignar el prototype, lo cual no es ni de cerca la mejor opcion.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varías cosas que no deberías hacer:

La primera es sobre hacer mezclas de ES5 y ES6, por poder hacerlo, puedes hacerlo pero no es lo más correcto, con hacer por ejemplo:

```
getFriends() {   

      return this.amigos; //Valdría!
    }
```

Si te has fijado bien en el caso anterior, no use `this.amigos.nombre` porque amigos no es un objeto que sepa.. Pero si lo es haber hecho una instancia del mismo y su estructura, me tomare este campo como un String.

Como ya te comente no es correcto hacer uso de ES5 y ES6 pero te lo pongo para que veas que si que funciona.

```js
class Persona {
    constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.edad = edad;
      this.hobbies = hobbies;
      this.amigos = amigos;

    }
    getFriends() {   
      Persona.prototype.returnFriend = function(){
      
        return this.amigos;
      }
      return this.returnFriend();
    }
    
}

let persona = new Persona("Alfredo", 99, "Liarla", "Marcos, Ramon, Victor");

console.log(persona.getFriends());
```

Ahora la buena practica:

```js
    class Persona {
        constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
          this.nombre = nombre;
          this.edad = edad;
          this.hobbies = hobbies;
          this.amigos = amigos;

        }
        
        getFriends(){   
        
            return this.amigos;
        }
        
    }

    let persona = new Persona("Alfredo", 99, "Liarla", "Marcos, Ramon, Victor");

    console.log(persona.getFriends());
```